# async client: `connection_lost` not called, results in ResourceWarning

Tags: python, sockets, python-asyncio

I am using asyncio client to connect and then disconnect from server.

- If I connect to server program on the same computer, <del>connection closes fine.</del> **Add:** When I started writing data to connection, this connection also started giving warnings *sometimes*. See second code version below.
- If I connect to device on the local network, I get `ResourceWarning` for unclosed transport.

**How do I close the connection correctly?**

I am using Python 3.6.0 (32-bit) on Windows 7 (64-bit).

## First attempt

Relevant code:

```
import asyncio
import logging
import warnings

class ClientConnection(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        transport.write_eof()  # Send EOF to close connection

    def connection_lost(self, exception):
        self.transport.close()
        super().connection_lost(exception)

def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    eventLoop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    eventLoop.set_debug(True)
    warnings.simplefilter('always', ResourceWarning)  # enables ResourceWarning
    #co = eventLoop.create_connection(ClientConnection, '127.0.0.1', 7001)     # Works without warning
    co = eventLoop.create_connection(ClientConnection, '192.168.10.66', 7001)  # Gives warning
    try:
        eventLoop.run_until_complete(co)
    finally:
        eventLoop.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Console output:

```
DEBUG:asyncio:Using selector: SelectSelector
DEBUG:asyncio:connect <socket.socket fd=240, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=6> to ('19
2.168.10.66', 7001)
DEBUG:asyncio:poll took 0.000 ms: 1 events
DEBUG:asyncio:<socket.socket fd=240, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=6, laddr=('192.168
.10.62', 64587), raddr=('192.168.10.66', 7001)> connected to 192.168.10.66:7001: (<_SelectorSocketTransport fd=240 read=
polling write=<idle, bufsize=0>>, <__main__.ClientConnection object at 0x005EBD90>)
DEBUG:asyncio:Close <_WindowsSelectorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=True>
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket fd=240, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto
=6, laddr=('192.168.10.62', 64587), raddr=('192.168.10.66', 7001)>
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\asyncio\selector_events.py:631: ResourceWarning: unclosed transport <_SelectorSoc
ketTransport fd=240>
  source=self)
```

## Second attempt

I did following changes to the code:

- Removed `transport.close()` from `connection_lost`
- Write some data to connection
- Added `data_received` and  `eof_received` callbacks
- Added more debug logs

Observations:

- I tried adding `transport.close()` to `connection_made`, but it will always result in `OSError: [WinError 10038]`. *Note: This probably another problem, so let's ignore this for now, and assume I won't do this.*
- When writing some data to socket, localhost connection also started to give warnings, but not always.
- When it gives warning, `connection_lost` is not called. Why?

Modified code:

```
import asyncio
import logging
import warnings

class ClientConnection(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        logging.debug('connection_made')
        self.transport = transport
        transport.write(b'1234\r')
        transport.write_eof()  # Send EOF to close connection
        #transport.close()  # Cannot close here either, gives 'OSError: [WinError 10038]'

    def connection_lost(self, exception):
        logging.debug('connection_lost')
        super().connection_lost(exception)

    def data_received(self, data):
        logging.debug('received {} bytes'.format(len(data)))

    def eof_received(self):
        logging.debug('EOF received')
        self.transport.close()

def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    eventLoop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    eventLoop.set_debug(True)
    warnings.simplefilter('always', ResourceWarning)  # enables ResourceWarning
    #co = eventLoop.create_connection(ClientConnection, '127.0.0.1', 7001)     # Works without warning
    co = eventLoop.create_connection(ClientConnection, '192.168.10.66', 7001)  # Gives warning
    try:
        eventLoop.run_until_complete(co)
        logging.debug('done')
    finally:
        eventLoop.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output when it succeeds:

```
...
DEBUG:root:EOF received
DEBUG:root:connection_lost
DEBUG:root:done
DEBUG:asyncio:Close <_WindowsSelectorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=True>
```

Output when it fails (note the lack of `connection_lost`):

```
...
DEBUG:root:EOF received
DEBUG:root:done
DEBUG:asyncio:Close <_WindowsSelectorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=True>
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket fd=240, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto
=6, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 63858), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 7001)>
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\asyncio\selector_events.py:631: ResourceWarning: unclosed transport <_SelectorSoc
ketTransport closing fd=240>
  source=self)
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce `WinError` on linux :-) transport.close() works fine.  Try adding `time.sleep(0.05)` before `.close()`.

Comment: @Udi Timeout doesn't seem to help, Windows seems to be picky about something. I'll probably ask another question about that. *But*, using delay alone seems to prevent the original problem. I need to do some testing, but it may be that my program simply does everything too fast. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Apparently under windows `write_eof` calls `close()`.  Also: Try running the loop forever and `stop()` it in `connection_lost`.

Answer (score 1):

Either wait for the server to close your connection, or use `transport.close()` to close the transport.  This will also trigger `connection_lost` (Don't call `transport.close()` from `connection_lost`!):

```
class ClientConnection(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        logging.debug("connection made, calling write eof")
        transport.write_eof()
        logging.debug("after calling write eof, calling close")
        transport.close()
        logging.debug("after calling close")

    def connection_lost(self, exception):
        logging.debug("connection lost")
        super().connection_lost(exception)
```

If you try a little more, you might get some `ResourceWarning`s for your local machine as well.  For example, try adding `transport.write(b'hello world!')` before `write_eof()` or make your local server respond slower.

Comment: You were right about sending data to localhost socket: It will trigger warning too. But I cannot close transport from `connection_made` either, I start getting OSErrors. I have amended the question.

Comment: Posting this is a new question will make more sense

Comment: OSError probably needs to go to another question (I'll make edit to exclude that), but this question still remains open: Sometimes `connection_lost` is not called, which gives the warning.

Comment: Consider changing the subject to "connection_lost not called"

Answer (score 1):

Try running the loop a little more.  Here is an example using `loop.run_forever()` and `loop.stop()`, assuming [echo server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#tcp-echo-server-protocol)s on local and remote machines:

```
import asyncio
import logging

import warnings


class ClientConnection(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        logging.debug("connection made, sending and calling write eof")
        transport.write(b'hello')
        transport.write_eof()
        logging.debug("after calling write eof")

    def data_received(self, data):
        logging.debug("Got: {}".format(data))
        super().data_received(data)

    def connection_lost(self, exception):
        logging.debug("connection lost")
        super().connection_lost(exception)
        loop.stop()


def test_echo(ip, port):
    logging.debug("Creating connection: {}:{}".format(ip, port))
    co = loop.create_connection(ClientConnection, ip, port)
    logging.debug("Starting loop...")
    print(loop.run_until_complete(co))
    logging.debug("...create_connection done, running loop forever...")
    loop.run_forever()
    logging.debug("Loop stopped")

    logging.debug('----------------')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    warnings.simplefilter('always')  # enables ResourceWarning

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.set_debug(True)

    test_echo('127.0.0.1', 7001)
    test_echo('54.175.103.105', 30000)

    logging.debug("done")
    loop.close()
```